# Ignore Endpoints from Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-application-insights, azure-traffic-manager

I have enabled Traffic Manager and the Monitoring Settings on my web role, now my Application Insights usage is completely unusable (11K impressions in a 24 hour period from Internet Explorer or Windows NT) and marks it as "real user traffic"?  Smh.

Further injury is the abysmal UX to "filter" route names from the blades especially when I have dozens of endpoints with no way to save.  Nor have I found a way to export to .pdf, so that I can share with advisors and/or investors.  I can export all of this data to JSON and create my own reports/analytics in an effort to spend time, resources, and money to recreate what's already been created and what I’m already paying for?  Does not compute.

**Is there a way to set a MVC Attribute/Filter on a particular endpoint or route so that it doesn't participate in any Application Insights server request tracking?**  Or is that just too easy?

Comment: +1 I'm really frustrated by all of those same issues. I despair a bit that they have gone so far down the track of building a deep and complex feature, seemingly ignoring the most obvious usability test - viewing real user traffic in a realistic production scenario and sharing the results.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a way to differentiate synthetic traffic in code, for example, by looking at headers, you can mark it as such by implementing telemetry initializer, for example:

```
public class SyntheticSourceInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (MySyntheticCheck(HttpContext.Current.Request))
        {
            telemetry.Context.Operation.SyntheticSource = "MySyntheticSource";
        }
    }
}
```

See [this blog post](http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/) on how to register telemetry initializer.

Once you have traffic identified as synthetic, you will be able to filter it out.

Comment: From about half-way down that post: "Telemetry initializers are powerful, but dangerous tool. They are called synchronously and block program execution flow.".  So it's multiple steps to set up, and it could blow up my whole site ... I guess we are stuck with useless user stats then ...